# webpack babel 'require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am having a strange browser warning when running webpack-dev-server, but no warning from webpack or webpack-dev-server.
I have looked for a solution but all similar past issues appear from mid 2015.

This level of tracking is beyond me at the moment.

Error as follows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:38204:2)
>       at **webpack_require** >(http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:38039:12)
>       at **webpack_require** >(http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:20467:25)
>       at **webpack_require** >(http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:55:13)
>       at **webpack_require** >(http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:20:30)
>       at http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:40:18
>       at http://localhost:8080/public/js/main.js:43:10

38204:

```
require('./browser_loader');
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/js',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    noParse: [/aws-sdk/],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }, 
    {
      test: /\.sass$/,
      loader: 'style!css!sass?indentedSyntax=true&sourceMap=true'
    }]
  },
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
//import '../css/main.css';
import '../css/main.sass';

render (<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Your issue is that Node.js is not loading through webpack.(thats where require resides)  I'm having the same issue right now, though it was working previously, have you had any other changes?

Comment: Yeah but none in my own code. I did update webpack. I was previously using browserify because webpack hates aws-sdk (for me) but was able to no-parse. Now I at least get the dev-server  notifications in the browser window and it's ignoring my ES6 stuff so I assumed it was at least running through babel, but no actual app output. However I concur. Even building through webpack standalone results in no output now (it did before I tried dev server)